# Problemas com salvar dados em form-model django

Tags: python, django, aplicação-web

Senhores, boa tarde!
Estou enfrentando um pequeno problema, fiz algumas mudanças em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo para estudos.
Me deparo com o seguinte, preencho a form tudo certo e quando vou dar um save, não acontece nada, não redireciona para o listamento nem nada.
O estranho que olho no terminal da um post.
 "POST /tickets/novo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3261
O que pode ser?
Ja tentei de tudo e não consigo resolver.

Segue o codigo da view : http://hastebin.com/uxorenoyiy.py
Segue o codigo do model: http://hastebin.com/uxogiqufoh.py
Quem pude me me ajudar agradeco.

Comment: Você está executando via `runserver` ou está num webserver "real" (ex.: Apache)? Há alguma coisa no console/arquivo de log? A flag `DEBUG` está `True`? A propósito, estou assumindo que `/tickets/novo/` mapeia para `ticket_create`, ou estou enganado?

Answer (score 2):

Note que o status da resposta foi `200` o que significa que **houve algum erro** de validação do form e que muito provavelmente um `render()` foi executado ao fim do request.

Se não houvesse erro de validação no form, a resposta seria um *redirect*, com status `302`.

Portanto, eu acredito que o `POST` está falhando na validação e a mesma página está sendo re-exibida pelo navegador. Tal como sugerido por @mgibsonbr.

Comment: Boa observação! De fato, a maioria dos `POST`s redireciona pra um `GET` após ter sucesso - para que o botão "Voltar" do navegador não repita acidentalmente o primeiro `POST`. Se não redirecionou, é porque falhou...

Comment: Correto. Essa prática é a mais recomendada e conhecida por PRG (POST-redirect-GET).

Answer (score 1):

Não tenho experiência com `Form`s, mas muito provavelmente seu problema é que faltam indicações de erros no seu template. Essa sua linha no `ticket_post`:

```
if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'ticket_novo.html',{'form': form})
```

Está dizendo: "se a validação falhar, mostre a mesma página em que já estou, com o mesmo formulário, com os mesmos valores que eu passei". Ou seja, é bem possível que a ação tenha mudado de página, e você nem percebeu, pois a página nova é idêntica à antiga (e transições de página [nem sempre vêm acompanhadas de uma indicação visual de que algo ocorreu](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/switch/)).

Entretanto, conforme [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14647770/520779) se seu template utilizar de alguma forma o `forms.errors` então a nova página poderá indicar visualmente o que ocorreu de errado. Você diz que " preencho a form tudo certo" mas não mostra nem o `Form` nem os dados que você tentou passar, então há de se considerar a possibilidade de ter havido erro ao preencher o formulário (i.e. dados inválidos), não?